# Facebook App use Friend Selector then Post to wall

Tags: facebook, post, fbml, friend

is there any way to use a friend selector and the post to the selected friend's walls?

If not- is there a way to use a friend selector, gather the ID's from that and then load within the FB.ui a new stream.publish to post to that user's wall?

I've been searching for awhile now and can't figure this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the FB.ui [feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) method - the user will be able to choose whether they want to share this content on their own wall, on a friends wall, in a group, on a page or in a private message.
You can however use the `to` parameter to initiate a share dialog directed at a specific user.